# How to extract custom JWT properties using servicestack

Tags: c#, servicestack, jwt

I can successfully authenticate against a servicestack endpoint secured with an `Authenticate` attribute when supplying the below JWT as a bearer token in an `authorization` header.

Some properties are easily accessible via `GetSession().Email` etc.

**Within a servicestack service, how would I extract the `UserId` and `AccountId` payload values?.**

```
{
  "iss": "aaaaaaaaaaa.net",
  "iat": 1485429344,
  "exp": 1516965344,
  "aud": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.net",
  "sub": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com",
  "given_name ": "aaaaaaaa",
  "family_name ": "aaaaaaaa",
  "Email": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@gmail.com",
  "Role": [
    "Manager",
    "Administrator"
  ],
  "UserId": "9df6e69f1a3c4be3a130b517736edb77",
  "AccountId": "b55da2067a514d83b6d12cb3852405e1"
}
```

Note:
I tried creating a custom `AuthUserSession` and using `SessionAs<CustomAuthUserSession>.AccountId`, but the `UserId` and `AccountId` properties remained empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's [JWT AuthProvider](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) only embeds the minimum info in the JWT Token by default. The JWT Documentation explains how to embed and extract additional metadata in the JWT Token:

#### [Modifying the JWT Payload](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#modifying-the-payload)

Whilst only limited info is embedded in the payload by default, all matching AuthUserSession properties embedded in the token will also be populated on the Session, which you can add to the payload using the CreatePayloadFilter delegate. So if you also want to have access to when the user was registered you can add it to the payload with:

```
new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings) 
{
    CreatePayloadFilter = (payload,session) => 
        payload["CreatedAt"] = session.CreatedAt.ToUnixTime().ToString()
}
```

You can also use the filter to modify any existing property which you can use to change the behavior of the JWT Token, e.g. we can add a special exception extending the JWT Expiration to all Users from Acme Inc with:

```
new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings) 
{
    CreatePayloadFilter = (payload,session) => {
        if (session.Email.EndsWith("@acme.com")) 
            payload["exp"] = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1).ToUnixTime().ToString();
    }
}
```

Likewise you can modify JWT Headers with the CreateHeaderFilter delegate and modify how the Users Session is populated with the PopulateSessionFilter.